# Return statements at the end of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have seen in many times in JavaScript code people add a `return true` at the end although not necessary. Does anyone know why?

```
var _globalString;
function doSomething()
{
    _globalString= _globalString +' do something';
    //some codes to do something more

    //finally adding a return true
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The thing that may have gotten some people into the habit was event handlers for forms, if you have, say:

```
<form onsubmit="return myfunction();">
```

and `myfunction()` returns true, the form submits, else if it returns false it doesn't. People doing it in general could've got the habit from this. Some languages require return values from functions, Javascript doesn't; and having `return true` at the end of most functions serves no purpose.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Erik's answer I would like to add

**return true** / **return false**  are also used when you want boolean value as a return.  And based on that return you execute some other function.

Answer (score 3):

A "return" inside a function automatically stops further execution of that function so for example:

```
function myFunc(){
    if(foo == 'bar'){
     /* do something */
    }else{
     /* do something */
    }
}
```

is the same as:

```
function myFunc(){
    if(foo == 'bar'){
        /* do something */
        return true;
    }

    /* if foo != 'bar' then whatever follows is executed... */

}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the question is about a return true *at* the end of the function.

Comment: Maybe not, but it does help people who got here by searching for "return true javascript."

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you are calling the function in onsumbit event

Example

```
 

<input type=sumit value=click Onsumbit='return function_name();">
```

While you are calling like , if the function return true only, form will be submit

If it return false , it wont submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Also you do not need to use return true or false in this case below

```
var newPage = "http://www.google.com";
function redirectURL(){
   window.location.href= newPage;
   return true;      //no return required
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to say why some programmers do certain things.

Maybe it's intended to indicate success/failure, but they haven't added any failing branches yet?